# Python Logging - Circular Log (last n entries)

Tags: python, logging

I know the Python `logging` library allows you to do 'circular' logging over multiple log files.  What I'm trying to do is simply have one file, `foo.log`, that is always <= **B** bytes in size; if the next append is going to put it over **B**, then things are deleted off the top.  I'd be just as happy to specify the max in terms of events, as well.

So, if this were the file rotation scheme, and item #4 exceeded B, you'd have:

```
foo.log.1    foo.log.2
---------    ---------
African      Swallow 
or
European
```

I'd like to simply wind up with:

```
foo.log
-------
or
European
Swallow
```

EDIT: Based on the comments below, people have legitimately noted this is a less-than-optimal format.  The motivation comes from debugging.  I have scripts using `psycopg2` to execute queries on a remote server that's stuck in 2002, roughly, with no internet connection.  Having it log everything it's sending to the db and then checking that log is the fastest way to see where something went wrong, and I have to point someone else to do it I don't want to introduce the complication of having them figure out which is the current log file.  The current solution is just to write the log and delete it if it gets too big.

Comment: That is a *very inefficient log format*, because once you hit the bytes limit, it requires rewriting the *whole log* each time you add a new line. There is no easy way to remove lines from the top when log lines have a variable length.

Comment: As such, there is no existing module or code that lets you do this; you'd end up rewriting your log file each time you want to add anything. You can write a custom log handler, but the performance will be so dismal it is just not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn notes, this type of log would be complicated to manage, and maybe inefficient (though this may or may not concern you).

A simple way to solve some part of the inefficiency is to use fixed record lengths. I.e. make each log entry the same (max) length.

Another way is to make your log database-based, and just make a record (variable or not) for each log entry. Let the db manager handle the adjustments. There are simple (RAM-based) databases to real, disk-based ones, all of which you can access with Python.

Yet another solution, if you're happy with a memory based log, is look into FIFO files.

Answer (score 0):

You could log to a file, with a couter/time at start of each line.

When you get to a certain point, just update from the top of the file again.

```
thefile = open('somebinfile', 'r+b')
thefile.seek(0)
```

Things to consider, when you seek to the top, and write to the file, you might only half overwrite next line to account for that you would need a unique line ending Char/String.